# Firebase rules write a switch / else if

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Short question: Is switch / else if supported by firebase rules ? I found nothing about this.

I have think about something like:

```
condition1 ? result1 : (condition2 ? result2: (condition3 :...)))
```

But not sure it works and it's not really a nice solution.

Comment: The entire rule has to be a single expression, which a switch case won't be (as far as I know).

Comment: Ok thank you for the validation. I just tried what I suggested and it works (but not really satisfying as it looks bad to do like that)

Comment: I'm not sure what to do about that. The rule you shared looks fine to me, but that's of course subjective. There's also not a lot we can do about that here, given that security rules can't contain a switch case (for the reason I gave).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Frank said in comment the answer to my question ( Is switch / else if supported by firebase rules ?) is no.

However there is an alternative as I suggested in my post.

Sample example of switch:

```
switch (foo) {
  case 1:
    return false;
    break;
  case 2:
    return true;
    break;
  default:
    return false;
}
```

equivalent rules will be:

```
foo === 1 ? false : (foo === 2 ? true : false)
```